# Why cannot I cast an object to its interface type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have a simple class

```
public class Message<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public Message(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

I want to create a base type `BaseEvent` for another set of classes, having a method `ToMessage` to convert to a message class like:

```
IConcreteEvent event = new ConcreteEvent(...);
Message<IConcreteEvent> = event.ToMessage();
```

Having the interface in the generic type of `Message<T>` is important because this object will be sent via web service.

I did something like

```
public interface IBaseEvent<T>
{
    Message<T> ToMessage();
}

public class BaseEvent<T> : IBaseEvent<T>
{
    public Message<T> ToMessage()
    {
        return new Message<T>((T)this); //error!
    }
}

public interface IConcreteEvent : IBaseEvent<IConcreteEvent>
{ }

public class ConcreteEvent : BaseEvent<IConcreteEvent>, IConcreteEvent
{ }
```

I get the error `Cannot convert BaseEvent<T> to T`.

I tried to force this by doing

```
T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(this, typeof(T));
return new Message<T>(value);
```

but I get the error `Object must implement IConvertible`.

If I debug types I see that `this` is of type `ConcreteEvent` while `typeof(T)` is `IConcreteEvent`.

Why is the cast not working?

Comment: Why would you expect that you can cast/convert `SomeGenericType<T>` to `T`? Can you cast `List<string>` to `string`?

Comment: @dymanoid I'm not casting `List<string>` to `string`, I'm casting the concrete type `ConcreteEvent` to its interface type `IConcreteEvent`

Comment: Nope, you cast `SomeType<T>` to `T`. This is your code: `(T)this`. In this case, `this` is an instance of `BaseEvent<T>` which you are trying to cast to `T`.

Comment: I understand the error but I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Usually you would have a member which return `T`, this member you can use to supply constructor parameter instead of `(T)this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution but it took some time.

This solution is **not safe**: if the class `ConcreteEvent` don't implement its interface `IConcreteEvent`, you'll get a runtime `InvalidCastException` with message `Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteEvent' to type 'IConcreteEvent'`

I also added the constraint `where T : IBaseEvent<T>` to the class `BaseEvent<T>` to better check types.

The method `ToMessage` can be implemented like

```
object value = this;
return new Message<T>((T)value);
```

Below a complete working example

```
void Main()
{
    IConcreteEvent e = new ConcreteEvent();
    Message<IConcreteEvent> msg = e.ToMessage();
}

public class Message<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public Message(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }
}

public interface IBaseEvent<T>
{
    Message<T> ToMessage();
}

public class BaseEvent<T> : IBaseEvent<T>
    where T : IBaseEvent<T>
{
    public Message<T> ToMessage()
    {
        object value = this;
        return new Message<T>((T)value);
    }
}

public interface IConcreteEvent : IBaseEvent<IConcreteEvent>
{ }

public class ConcreteEvent : BaseEvent<IConcreteEvent>, IConcreteEvent
{ }
```